# C++ std::sort does not work with pointer to vector

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

After much searching, it seems that a pointer to a vector is not the best thing to do. However, the following code bugs me too much:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <algorithm>
  3 #include <vector>
  4
  5
  6 class Hdr
  7 {
  8     public:
  9     std::vector<long> *order;
 10     bool operator()(long i1, long i2) const;
 11     Hdr(int N);
 12     ~Hdr();
 13 };
 14
 15 Hdr::Hdr(int N)
 16 {
 17     order = new std::vector<long>(N,0);
 18     for(int k=0;k<N;k++) (*order)[k] = -k;
 19 };
 20
 21 Hdr::~Hdr()
 22 {
 23     order->clear();
 24     delete order;
 25 };
 26
 27 bool Hdr::operator()(long i1, long i2) const
 28 {
 29     return (i1<i2);
 30 };
 31
 32 int main(void)
 33 {
 34     Hdr mhdr(1000);
 35     std::sort(mhdr.order->begin(),mhdr.order->end(),mhdr);
 36
 37     printf("value at 300 = %d\n",mhdr.order->at(300));
 38 };
```

with gcc 4.3 on Linux, the executable gives "double free or corruption". So I commented out line 24, and it throws 'std::out_of_range'. Apparently, line 35 (sort) messes everything up when a dynamically allocated vector is passed to std::sort. Or I just had a big blunder somewhere. Please help!! If I change line 9 to std::vector order then things seem fine; however I can't keep wondering what went wrong with the pointer to vector.

Comment: To help those who copy/paste your code to work on it, it would be better to include comments with reference lines than to include line numbers.

Answer (score 12):

You are not following the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three):  you haven't defined a copy constructor and copy assignment operator for your class.

You make a copy of `mhdr` when you pass it as the functor to `std::sort`.  The `order` data member of that copy and of the original `mhdr` both point to the same object.  The copy is destroyed, causing the object pointed to by its `order` to be deleted, then the original is destroyed when `main` ends, causing a double deletion, undefined behavior, and other fun things to happen.

(In fact, even more copies might be made inside of `std::sort`, so it might crash even earlier.)

Why are you dynamically allocating the `std::vector`?  If there are any good reasons to do that, there are very few of them.

Comment: Deleted my answer in favour of voting this one up. :)

Answer (score 5):

You're passing `mhdr` by value to `std::sort()`, with a default copy constructor that duplicates the pointer to your vector, and `delete`s it when that instance goes out of scope. That's not what you want.

You should probably use a comparator object distinct from the thing holding that vector, or reference count the pointer to the vector (using an appropriate smart pointer class, probably).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `bool operator()()` on that class - the `long`s can be sorted with default comparison (see [`std::sort`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/sort.html)). The runtime-reported problem is that the third argument is *copied*, and you don't have a copy constructor, nor copy assignment operator in `Hdr` (see [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)).

Comment: what's the point of sorting a vector<long> unless the longs are actually the index of something? so thanks for your answer but pls don't mention default long comparison.

Comment: `std::vector` guarantees contiguos storage of elements. Sorting a vector might be a lot faster then building say `std::set`. longs are often used as prices or whatever, so this does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that std::sort takes the comparison functor by value, so the destructor will be invoked for the copy and for the original `mhdr` object, and thus, since you havent supplied a copy constructor, `order` will be deleted twice.

The easiest fix would be to use a normal `std::vector` instead of a pointer to a `std::vector`. By doing this the implicit copy constructor will work for you.

Beside that you could define your copy constructor and make a deep copy of the `order` vector, or use a smart pointer to wrap it.

But the best solution would be to make the compare function a static member function (or a global function) and using that as parameter for `std::sort`. You should always use dedicated functor classes. DONT just add an `operator()` to a class which already does something else. It might work as expected, but most certainly it wont be as effective as a dedicated functor class, because much more copy-operations might be needed (for member variables, like in this case).
Of course you still should fix the copy-constructor of the `Hdr` class (or just declare a copy-ctor without definition, to remove the implicit one, which fails in this case).

Comment: Thank you. I use operator() to compare so that it has access to member of Hdr. Please show me how to access member of Hdr in a dedicated functor class. Is there a way to force std::sort to use the comparison functor by reference?

Comment: you can use a static member function instead, or declare the functor class as friend. Or in your case `std::less<long>` (`#include <functional>`) will do.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, the main cause of it is that when you pass mhdr as the comparator, you are making a copy.  This copy contains a pointer to the same vector.  When that copy gets destroyed, that vector gets destroyed, corrupting the collection that was between your iterators.

This would have been apparent if you prevented copying and assignment by declaring those operators private and not implementing then.

The reason you got into this mess is that your Hdr class has two distinct functions -- maintaining the vector, and having the comparator function.  Classes should do one thing, and one thing well.

The solution below fixes these problems, as well as some other problems like exposing data members as `public` (though I preserved the pointer to the `vector` since I suspect you were trying to illustrate something about that case even though I agree with the other answerers that this is a questionable decision)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Hdr
{
    public:
          Hdr(int N);
        ~Hdr();

        typedef std::vector<long>::iterator OrderIt;
        OrderIt orderBegin();
        OrderIt orderEnd();
        long orderAt(int index) const;

    private:
        Hdr& operator=(const Hdr&);
        Hdr(const Hdr&);

        std::auto_ptr<std::vector<long> > order;
};

class Comparator
{
    public:
        bool operator()(long i1, long i2) const;

};

Hdr::Hdr(int N)
{
    order = std::auto_ptr<std::vector<long> >(new std::vector<long>(N,0));
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++) 
    {
        (*order)[k] = -k;
    }
};

Hdr::~Hdr()
{
    order->clear();
};

Hdr::OrderIt Hdr::orderBegin()
{
    return order->begin();
}

Hdr::OrderIt Hdr::orderEnd()
{
    return order->end();
}

long Hdr::orderAt(int nIndex) const
{
    return order->at(nIndex);
}

bool Comparator::operator()(long i1, long i2) const
{
    return (i1<i2);
};

int main(void)
{
    Hdr mhdr(1000);
    std::sort(mhdr.orderBegin(),mhdr.orderEnd(), Comparator());
    printf("value at 300 = %d\n",mhdr.orderAt(300));
};
```

Comment: `order.reset(new ...)` is a bit more concise.

Comment: Cool -- wasn't familiar with that.  Always hated having to explicitly call the constructor.